# Need help in making calculator in Android

Tags: android, calculator

Hello i need help in making a calculator in Android i have made a bit myself but i'm looking for a way in which u add 2 numbers e.g. 5+5 than the answer comes as 10, not first by adding number 5 than replacing it with another number and than it gets added, is there a certain way to do it, thanks in advance e.g. How to i change this part:

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.plus:
                if (operand1 == 0) {
                    operand1 = Integer.parseInt(resultText.getText().toString());
                    resultText.setText("0");
                    operator = "+";
                } else {
                    operand2 = Integer.parseInt(resultText.getText().toString());
                    answer = operand1 + operand2;
                    operand1 = answer;
                    resultText.setText("" + answer);
                    operand2 = 0;
                    answer = 0;
                    operator = "";
                }
                break;
```

to make it e.g 5+5=10 rather than 5 than adding and replacing it with another number and than it gets added.

Here is my full code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


EditText resultText;
Button one1, two1, three1;
Button plus1;
Button four1;
Button five1;
Button six1;
Button minus1;
Button seven1;
Button eight1;
Button nine1;
Button multiply1;
Button clear;
Button zero1;
Button square1;
Button divide1, equals;

int operand1, operand2, answer;
String input, operator;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    resultText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.space);
    resultText.setText("0");
    one1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.one);
    two1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.two);
    three1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.three);
    plus1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.plus);
    four1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.four);
    five1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.five);
    six1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.six);
    minus1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.minus);
    seven1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.seven);
    eight1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eight);
    nine1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nine);
    multiply1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.multiply);
    clear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.c);
    zero1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.zero);
    square1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.square);
    divide1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.divide);
    equals = (Button) findViewById(R.id.equal);

    one1.setOnClickListener(this);
    two1.setOnClickListener(this);
    three1.setOnClickListener(this);
    plus1.setOnClickListener(this);
    four1.setOnClickListener(this);
    five1.setOnClickListener(this);
    six1.setOnClickListener(this);
    minus1.setOnClickListener(this);
    seven1.setOnClickListener(this);
    eight1.setOnClickListener(this);
    nine1.setOnClickListener(this);
    multiply1.setOnClickListener(this);
    clear.setOnClickListener(this);
    zero1.setOnClickListener(this);
    square1.setOnClickListener(this);
    divide1.setOnClickListener(this);
    equals.setOnClickListener(this);


}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.plus:
            if (operand1 == 0) {
                operand1 = Integer.parseInt(resultText.getText().toString());
                resultText.setText("0");
                operator = "+";
            } else {
                operand2 = Integer.parseInt(resultText.getText().toString());
                answer = operand1 + operand2;
                operand1 = answer;
                resultText.setText("" + answer);
                operand2 = 0;
                answer = 0;
                operator = "";
            }
            break;
        case R.id.minus:
            if (operand1 == 0) {
                operand1 = Integer.parseInt(resultText.getText().toString());
                resultText.setText("0");
                operator = "-";
            } else {
                operand2 = Integer.parseInt(resultText.getText().toString());
                answer = operand1 - operand2;
                operand1 = answer;
                resultText.setText("" + answer);
                operator = "";
                operand2 = 0;
                answer = 0;
            }
            break;
        case R.id.multiply:
            if (operand1 == 0) {
                operand1 = Integer.parseInt(resultText.getText().toString());
                operator = "*";
                resultText.setText("0");
            } else {
                operand2 = Integer.parseInt(resultText.getText().toString());
                answer = operand1 * operand2;
                operand1 = answer;
                resultText.setText("" + answer);
                operand2 = 0;
                answer = 0;
                operator = "";
            }
            break;
        case R.id.divide:
            if (operand1 == 0) {
                operand1 = Integer.parseInt(resultText.getText().toString());
                operator = "/";
                resultText.setText("0");
            } else {
                operand2 = Integer.parseInt(resultText.getText().toString());
                answer = operand1 / operand2;
                operand1 = answer;
                resultText.setText("" + answer);
                operand2 = 0;
                answer = 0;
                operator = "";
            }
            break;
        case R.id.equal:
            if (operand1 != 0) {
                operand2 = Integer.parseInt(resultText.getText().toString());
                switch (operator) {
                    case "+":
                        answer = operand1 + operand2;
                        break;
                    case "-":
                        answer = operand1 - operand2;
                        break;
                    case "*":
                        answer = operand1 * operand2;
                        break;
                    case "/":
                        answer = operand1 / operand2;
                        break;
                    default:
                        answer=0;
                        break;
                }
                operand1 = answer;
                resultText.setText("" + answer);
                operand2 = 0;
                answer = 0;
            }
            break;
        case R.id.square:
            operand1 = Integer.parseInt(resultText.getText().toString());
            answer = operand1 * operand1;
            resultText.setText("" + answer);
            operand1 = answer;
            break;
        case R.id.c:
            operand1 = 0;
            operand2 = 0;
            answer = 0;
            resultText.setText("0");
            break;

        default:
            input = resultText.getText().toString();
            if (input.equals("0"))
                input = v.getTag().toString();
            else
                input += v.getTag().toString();
            resultText.setText(input);
            break;
    }
}

}
```

Try to see if u can help me as much as you can.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, you want single edit text field, where you enter string "5+5", and then the calculator will print 10 in result? Because the code you posted is almost simulating classic calculator, chaining the operations upon previous result.

Comment: You mean showing the operands on the screen before adding them?

Comment: yes thats what i mean i want to add 2 numbers e.g 5+5=10 i don't want to replace the number and than get the result right i for example if i write 5 press + than add another number the number gets replaced and after equals it turns to 10 i don't want that i simple like 5+5 than when i press equals it turns to 10, i want 5+5 to show on the textfield

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand what you're asking exactly, but it looks like you're setting the operand1 to answer before displaying the string that you want ("5 + 5").

Try setting your code to something like the following:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.plus:
            if (operand1 == 0) {
                operand1 = Integer.parseInt(resultText.getText().toString());
                resultText.setText("0");
                operator = "+";
            } else {
                operand2 = Integer.parseInt(resultText.getText().toString());
                answer = operand1 + operand2;
                resultText.setText(operand1 + operator + operand2);
            }
            break;
```

Then create a separate button for = that will trigger the following:

```
resultText.setText(answer);
answer = 0;
operand1 = 0;
operand2 = 0;
operator = "";
```

This still seems clumsy, but without seeing more of your code I can't really tell if it matches what you're building or not. Basically, display the full string ("5 + 5"), then when enter is pressed display the answer ("10") and clean up all your other variables. If you don't want to have the answer triggered by a separate button, you could potentially have it set to a delay.